# laravel - radiobutton selected only in certain condition

Tags: laravel, if-statement, radio-button, enable-if

I'd need to disable a radio button based on a condition. Here is my try, but it is not working. How can this be achived?

```
 <input type="radio" id="type100" name="type" enabled="{{ ((auth()->user()->type100) > 10)  }}" value="100" checked>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
<input type="radio" id="type100" name="type" {{ auth()->user()->type100 > 10 ? '' : 'disabled' }} value="100" checked>
```

Comment: thank you! it works! can also two conditions be concatenated? so > 10 and < 100 for example?

Comment: @sharkyenergy yes you can use `&&` to achieve that.